# Войти в админку копии сайта на WP

Tags: wordpress

При попытке зайти в **админку копии сайта** (после переноса его не сервер) происходит редирект на боевой сайт.

Например,

- пытаюсь зайти сюда `сopysite.ru/wp-admin`
- попадаю сюда `site.ru/wp-admin`

Кто сталкивался с таким, подскажите где и что нужно поменять?

Comment: в мануале представлены несколько способов, я использовал третий http://dimox.name/moving-the-site-on-new-domain/

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После переноса Wordpress вы не поменяли все ссылки для сайта в базе, зайдите в базу, таблица wp_options и там поменяйте все site.ru на  сopysite.ru. И ещё проверьте на наличие старого домена в файле .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Неправильно перенесли. Переносить лучше всего с пом. плагинов для клонирования/миграции, которые исправляют сериализованные массивы. Напр [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/).

Большинство описанных в интернете способов говорит о замене в таблице `wp_options` значений `siteurl` и `home`. Это устаревшая информация. Они не учитывают пути к файлам и применения адреса в сериализованных массивах. что применяется во многих современных тема, плагинах и даже в настройках ВП. Это чревато разными проблемами - от потерь виджетов и стилей до нерабочего функционала тем и плагинов. Ну и возможны другие, менее явные ошибки и проблемы "непонятного" происхождения.

Корректное исправления уже после переноса можно сделать [этим скриптом](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). Но действовать нужно аккуратно и многопроходно - от больших вхождений к меньшим, постоянно проверяя в демо-режиме что и где найдено. Не забывать также про наличие экранированных спецсимволов в базе.