# Ошибка во вход админ. панели в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Был перенесен сайт на другой хостинг. Выдает ошибку:

```
. in /var/www/vhosts/12/145514/webspace/httpdocs/technosector.kz/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3669 Warning: stream_socket_client(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in /var/www/vhosts/12/145514/webspace/httpdocs/technosector.kz/wp-includes/class-wp-http-streams.php on line 150 Warning: stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to tcp://repository.alchemythemes.com:80 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known) in /var/www/vhosts/12/145514/webspace/httpdocs/technosector.kz/wp-includes/class-wp-http-streams.php on line 150
```

Подозрения на путь `var/www/vhosts/12/145514/webspace`, сейчас он другой. Где его можно поменять?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress)

Answer (score 0):

Просто заменить - побьются сериализованные массивы.

Я [уже писал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/619625) в ответе к вопросу «Войти в админку копии сайта на WP», как лучше делать перенос и как исправить уже перенесенное:

> Неправильно перенесли. Переносить лучше всего с пом. плагинов для клонирования/миграции, которые исправляют сериализованные массивы. Напр [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/).
>
> Большинство описанных в интернете способов говорит о замене в таблице `wp_options` значений `siteurl` и `home`. Это устаревшая информация. Они не учитывают пути к файлам и применения адреса в сериализованных массивах. что применяется во многих современных тема, плагинах и даже в настройках ВП. Это чревато разными проблемами - от потерь виджетов и стилей до нерабочего функционала тем и плагинов. Ну и возможны другие, менее явные ошибки и проблемы "непонятного" происхождения.
>
> Корректное исправления уже после переноса можно сделать [этим скриптом](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/). Но действовать нужно аккуратно и многопроходно - от больших вхождений к меньшим, постоянно проверяя в демо-режиме что и где найдено. Не забывать также про наличие экранированных спецсимволов в базе.